# SQL select date range

Tags: sql, select

My problem is that I want only to SELECT the product the customer bought in date range before the current date at 8 week.

Tables: `Salesinvoiceheader` and `SalesinvoiceDetail`

[image: Screenshot of data]

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. You've already got one product specific answer - hopefully for your dbms.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query:

```
SELECT product FROM Customer WHERE date > DATEADD(week, -8, GETDATE());
```

**Edited: **

`SELECT product FROM  SalesinvoiceDetail WHERE Invoicedate > DATEADD(week, -8, GETDATE());`

Comment: I want to Select according to Invoicedate, before the current date at 8 week, Results show the product over time.

Comment: Time doesn't matter here as long as all of them are same. By the way, can I ask you that, did you mean the products which customer bought before 8 weeks from today?

Comment: Thanks. And I want Join 2 table after select result? Table have Column Product, InvoiceCode, InvoiceDate, customercode.

Comment: I'm not sure what "before the current date at 8 week" means. It could be that it needs to be a `>` rather than `<`.

Comment: Note that this is a product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP and the rest of us which dbms this is for.

Comment: I have written code like you but it shows the wrong result, you have other solution direction or better help me. EX: date current is 2017-05-12=> Result select Products that customers have purchased within the last 8 weeks or 2 month: 2017-05-12 to 2017-03-12.